# How to return rows of a df that contain strings from a character list

Tags: r

I have a character list. I would like to return rows in a df that contain any of the strings in the list in a given column.

I have tried things like:

```
hits <- df %>%
filter(column, any(strings))


strings <- c("ape", "bat", "cat")

head(df$column)
[1] "ape and some other text here"          
[2] "just some random text"
[3] "Something about cats"
```

I would like only rows 1 and 3 returned

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Here is the first step to getting a good answer: [ask].

Comment: Thank you. It posted before I was fully finished. Apologize for wasting your time

Comment: Better.  But now we need some more context.  Providing a small reproducible example from the data and the desired result given that data would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grepl()` with a regular expression matching any of the strings in your `strings` vector:

```
strings <- c("ape", "bat", "cat")
```

Firstly, you can collapse the `strings` vector to the regex you need:

```
regex <- paste(strings, collapse = "|")
```

Which gives:

```
> regex <- paste(strings, collapse = "|")
> regex
[1] "ape|bat|cat"
```

The pipe symbol `|` acts as an **or** operator, so this regex `ape|bat|cat` will match `ape` *or* `bat` *or* `cat`.

If your data.frame `df` looks like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 1
                        column
                         <chr>
1 ape and some other text here
2        just some random text
3         something about cats
```

Then you can run the following line of code to return just the rows matching your desired strings:

```
df[grepl(regex, df$column), ]
```

The output is as follows:

```
> df[grepl(regex, df$column), ]
# A tibble: 2 x 1
                        column
                         <chr>
1 ape and some other text here
2         something about cats
```

Note that the above example is case-insensitive, it will only match the lower case strings exactly as specified. You can overcome this easily using the `ignore.case` parameter of `grepl()` (note the upper case `Cats`):

```
> df[grepl(regex, df$column, ignore.case = TRUE), ]
# A tibble: 2 x 1
                        column
                         <chr>
1 ape and some other text here
2         something about Cats
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a regular expression.

```
aColumn <- c("ape and some other text here","just some random text","Something about cats")
aColumn[grepl("ape|bat|cat",aColumn)]
```

...and the output:

```
> aColumn[grepl("ape|bat|cat",aColumn)]
[1] "ape and some other text here" "Something about cats"        
>
```

One an also set up the regular expression in an R object, as follows.

```
# use with a variable
strings <- "ape|cat|bat"
aColumn[grepl(strings,aColumn)]
```